# Unresolved identifier Error Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, class, swift2

I can't solve this problem I have a variable named row but swift doesn't see it. Error is "use of unresolved identifier "row""

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.mertbarutcuoglu.com/?json=get_posts")!

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let urlContent = data {

            do {

                let jSonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                let posts =  jSonData["posts"] as? NSArray

                let row = Int(posts!.count)
            } catch {}
        }
    }

    task.resume()


    return row.count
}
```

Comment: BTW you can save yourself some indentation by using `guard let urlContent = data else { /*handle else case */ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *unresolved identifier* is your minor problem. This code will **NEVER** return the expected value.
You **cannot** use an asynchronous method in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Put the code to retrieve the data in `viewDidLoad` and return in `numberOfRowsInSection` just the number of posts.

And use Swift native collection types.

```
var posts = [[String:AnyObject]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.mertbarutcuoglu.com/?json=get_posts")!
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            do {
                let jSonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
                posts =  jSonData["posts"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                self.tableView.reloadData()                  
            } catch let error as NSError{
              print(error)
            }
        } else {
            print("NSURLSession error:", error!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
```